# What ffmpeg/avconv format and container will Adobe Premiere Pro accept, out-of-box?

Tags: video, file-formats, premiere, ffmpeg

All of these converted, but Premiere Pro only loads the audio.  I use Ctrl-I to import the videos, and they come up as waveforms, and can only be placed on audio tracks.

These examples use avconv, but I also have ffmpeg, and don't really care which as long as it works  :-)

```
avconv -i v1raw.AVI  -c:a copy -c:v mpeg2video  v1conv.mpeg
avconv -i v1raw.AVI  -c:a copy -c:v mpeg2video  v1conv.avi
avconv -i v1raw.AVI  -c:a copy -c:v mpeg4  v1conv.m4v
avconv -i v1conv.avi  -c:a copy -c:v copy  v1conv_copy.mpeg
```

Here's the data for my input file (incase it helps).

```
Input #0, avi, from 'v1raw.AVI':
  Duration: 00:05:28.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9592 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: adpcm_ms, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 176 kb/s
```

And my available video encoding formats from avconv.

```
a64multi, a64multi5, asv1, asv2, bmp, cljr, dnxhd, dpx, 
dvvideo, ffv1, ffvhuff, flashsv, flv, gif, h261, h263, h263p, 
huffyuv, jpegls, libdirac, libschroedinger, libtheora, libvpx, 
libx264, libxvid, ljpeg, mjpeg, mpeg1video, mpeg2video, 
mpeg4, msmpeg4, msmpeg4v2, pam, pbm, pcx, pgm, pgmyuv, png, 
ppm, qtrle, rawvideo, roqvideo, rv10, rv20, sgi, snow, svq1
```

<sup>[see full codec info](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=z4qsWpdh)</sup>

I'd be happy to post anything else that has the slightest chance of helping.

Comment: Which version of Premiere Pro? Why not import `v1raw.AVI` into Premiere?

Comment: It's CS5.  The raw (original from camear) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Premiere Pro CS5 should be able to import H.264 video, IIRC, however it may be having trouble with the audio and/or container format. With ffmpeg try re-muxing the video stream without the audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input -an -codec:v copy output.mp4 -an -codec:v copy output.avi
```

If both `output.mp4` and `output.avi` work then we know that the issue lies with the audio (although H.264 with b-frames in AVI probably isn't a great idea). You can re-encode the audio and keep the video:

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v copy -codec:a pcm_s16le output.avi
```

If the first command does not work with Premiere, then you may need to re-encode. This is a good use case for an editor friendly, lossless intermediate file:

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v utvideo -codec:a pcm_s16le output.avi
```

Close Premiere, install [Ut Video](http://umezawa.dyndns.info/archive/utvideo/) (scroll to the bottom of the page), open Premiere, and import your video. You can do your editing, and then export to your final format using the crappy Adobe Media Encoder, or export to another lossless file, and then use ffmpeg to provide whatever you need. Alternatively, if you're using Windows you can use [Debugmode FrameServer](http://www.debugmode.com/frameserver/) and encode directly with ffmpeg from Premiere. See [How to encode with ffmpeg from Adobe Premiere Pro](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/FFmpegPremierePro) for instructions.

If you need a recent ffmpeg for Windows see [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: Thanks, the MP4 worked for me.  I can just grab one of the audios from the videos that were *only* giving me audio, and call it a day.  Btw, I had to change -codec:v to -vcodec, and I don't have utvideo; any idea why?

Comment: Your ffmpeg is old.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the help.  I'll get the newest ffmpeg.  I assume utvideo comes with the default build?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Yes, the native `utvideo` encoder and decoder is included with ffmpeg, but usage of `libutvideo` is also an option if included with a build.